# Difference between structural and ontological metaphors?

Tags: cognitive-linguistics, metaphor

What is the difference between structural and ontological metaphors?

*Time is money* is an ontological metaphor that borrows an abstract quality of time to something concrete like money. But could *time is money* be also considered a structural metaphor, since it highlights relationships and patterns within our experience?

Comment: If these are formal types of metaphors, you need to provide definitions. I doubt the are. I can take just about any adjective and prepend it to the word metaphor.

Comment: @Lambie, this typology [apparently](https://www.thoughtco.com/structural-metaphor-1692146) comes from Lakoff’s and Johnson’s *Metaphors We Live By*.

Comment: "Metaphor" is an overloaded concept. The intended form of this saying is surely *Time = Money* as a term which is physical-financially more or less correct. We speak of proportional factors. If that's a metaphor, I don't want to be a linguist.